# I got 78 errors when building my project after updating Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I was using Xcode 7 beta Swift 2 , then I just updated my Xcode to 7.2. Then I got 78 errors and I can't build my app! The errors down below

[image]

[image]

And Yes I've deleted all my libs and imported them again!
Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try clean with `Shift+Command+K`? Does it any help?

Comment: I did that, still getting errors

Comment: Did you update Xcode from somewhere other than developer.apple.com or the App Store?

Comment: @Rob I didn't got how to get on validate settings, I'm sorry but english isn't my original language, Can you explain more please?

Comment: @PetahChristian Hi, I download it from this link: https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2/Xcode_7.2.dmg

Comment: Interesting discussion here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/9176#9176